# Do Sandbox Accounts need to have Payouts added to them by PayPal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

On my Paypal developer dashboard My Account page I see a little green check mark for Payouts on sandbox accounts and 'Enable' for live accounts.  But when I log into the sandbox account itself and go to Mass Payments it is telling me I need to contact Paypal to have this service enabled.

Is this not the same as Payouts?  And if it is, do I need to have it enabled for a sandbox account?  Or is it already enabled for sandbox accounts?

I am trying to make some calls to the Payouts API on this sandbox account and it is giving me an Authorization Error.

Cheers

**UPDATE**

Here is the scope from the token request:

> https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing https://uri.paypal.com/services/vault/payment-tokens/read https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-buyer https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/realtimepayment https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/update-seller https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/payment/authcapture openid https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-seller Braintree:Vault https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/refund https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://uri.paypal.com/services/reporting/search/read https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts https://uri.paypal.com/services/vault/payment-tokens/readwrite https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.* https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks

**RESPONSE ERROR**

This is the response I get when making a call...

```
{"name":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR","message":"Authorization error occurred.","debug_id":"7c7330885dfd7","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors","links":[]}
```

Comment: Show the scopes returned with your token request. Show the error when using payouts.

Comment: Thanks again - I added the scopes to the question.

Comment: So Payouts is there, that's good. How about the error when you attempt to use it?

Comment: Updated the question to add the response error.  Just says 'Authorization Error'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it seems you do need to contact PayPal's technical support to request that Payouts be enabled for a sandbox account. This didn't use to be the case.

More important is the live account owner contacting PayPal's business support to request the feature, since there is no point integrating something in sandbox mode if it will not be approved for live use.

Comment: Thanks, I just sent a support request to find out how I can enable it on this sandbox account.  At this point I just want to test this feature to see how it compares to some other options (i.e Stripe Connect) we are looking at.